# ASP.Net web API Help Page - no content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I installed the package from NuGet, uncommented the line from HelpPageConfig.cs-

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

I've set the same file under Properties->Build->XML documentation file,
Added a new Global.asax.cs file in which I call for registration for all the areas under Application_Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
}
```

I've added some summary for some of my controllers:

```
public class IncidentsController : ApiController
{
     /// <summary>
     /// this is the summary
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="incidentId">this is incidentId</param>
     /// <returns>it returns something</returns>
     [Route("{incidentId}")]
     [HttpGet]
     public object GetIncidentById(int incidentId)
     {
            return Incidents.SingleOrDefault(i => i.id == incidentId);
     }
}
```

when i run the webpage and go to '/help' the only thing i see is

> ASP.NET Web API Help Page
>
> Introduction
>
> Provide a general description of your APIs here.

and an empty page after that...

I tried to debug that and in HelpController.cs in:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            ViewBag.DocumentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
            return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
}
```

I get no ApiDescriptions.

what am I missing? I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 13):

I was able to solve this by adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configure (WebApiConfig.Register);` in my `Application_Start ()` method. Because my application uses OWIN I was registering my APIs only in `Startup.Configuration (IAppBuilder app)`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was my exact problem and your answer solved it for me!

Comment: This was my issue as well.  Thank you!

Comment: You are a Godsend! THANK YOU!!

Comment: Awesome! worked for me too. I was also using OWIN and registering in Startup. THANKS!

Comment: if this answer is a little too cryptic please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921215/cant-get-asp-net-web-api-2-help-pages-working-when-using-owin?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped you XMl Path right ?

Have you added summary to your methods ?
/// 
/// Gets some very important data from the server.
///

This should help Have you checked [WebApi Help Page Description](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24284413/1481690)