# ASP.NET Web API not returning custom error information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET Web API 2 action method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Create(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
   //...

   if (success)
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

   return CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "you done bad");
}
```

Until I did "something", upon error it would return http 400 with the custom error text "you done bad".  That's the expected result.

It no longer returns the custom text; it just returns the standard "Bad request". 
 Have been trying to understand what changed to make this happen.

So I tried:

```
var response = new { message = "you done bad" };
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
```

Same result.

I then created a new, clean Web API project and I get the result I expect.

How did I break my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is related to the CustomErrors configuration in web.config. From @HaukurHaf's answer at [Error messages returned from Web API method are omitted in non-dev environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23610880/46249):

> Had the same issue. It's indeed because of the custom errors setting.
>
> In a real world scenario, you would definitely want to use a custom
>   error page in your application, but in order for custom exception
>   messages to work in the WebAPI you need to disable the custom errors
>   page.
>
> How to fix this? Luckily, you can use the `<location>` element in your
>   web.config to solve this.
>
> Solution:
>
> ```
>  <!-- General for the application -->
>   <system.web>
>     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="YourCustomErrorPage.aspx"/>
>   </system.web>
>
>   <!-- Override it for paths starting with api (your WebAPI) -->
>   <location path="api">
>      <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off" />
>      </system.web>
>   </location>
> ```
>
> I use this method in my own app, works well.

While I do see that this works, I don't understand why the CustomErrors section breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method as below

```
    [Route("User/GetUserIDCustomMessage")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUserIDCustomMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, int Id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        if (Id == 1)
        {
            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else {

            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest , "YOu type bad");

        }
        return response;
    }
```

When I give 1 , it will give me OK message with 200 status code , otherwise it will give 400/Bad Request , with body message 'YOu type bad'

Comment: This gives the same result - I still have the problem.  Your code is functionally equivalent to mine.  Your CreateResponse returns an HttpResponseMessage as well.

Comment: I agree - "it works on *your* machine". But your code is functionally equivalent to mine and mine isn't working for me. Anyway, I've found the problem and posted the answer above.

Comment: Its Ok ,Thanks your answer :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably consider creating a instance of `HttpResponseMessage` and add your custom error message to its `Content` property.

```
HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
msg.Content = new StringContent("you done bad");
return msg;
// or can re-throw it
//throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

Please check the following link for details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx