# httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" is not working when specified in a web.config file in a subdirectory of a website

Tags: iis

I have an IIS website which contains both "normal" pages and API endpoints. When I make a request to one of the API endpoints, I want the error response from the API to be passed through.

So I've put the following in the web.config file within the directory of the endpoint (ex. the endpoint is /apis/documentUpload, I'm using /apis/web.config)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that it's not working.  I still get the IIS default error pages.  If I move that setting into my site root (/web.config), then it works, but I don't want to pass through errors for every page in the site -- just for the APIs.  I haven't found anything in my searches saying that the setting only works at the site level, so I'm hoping that I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: You can clear your browser's cache and try again, and then check if it's still the same issue.

Comment: I'm using Postman, so I don't think there is a browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Custom error page is not working for api, if you want to custom error work in the webapi you need to disable the custom errors page, but you can use the  element in your web.config to solve this.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="YourCustomErrorPage.aspx"/>
</system.web>

<!-- Override it for paths starting with api (your WebAPI) -->
 <location path="api">
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43709114/13336642.